# how to treat a percentage division by zero?

Tags: java, c++, math, statistics

I have data on asset prices, some of the prices are 0. My formula for calculating the return is ((curPrice/prevPrice)-1)*100. What is the best approach to take if the previous price is zero? Is it valid to treat the percentage increase as 100%?

would the following be valid?

```
previousPrice == 0 ? return 100 : ((curPrice/prevPrice)-1)*100;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: check now, i made modifications

Comment: This question is not a programming question, but a requirements question. You have to decide what the correct behavior is, based on knowledge of your problem domain. Once you've decided that, writing the code should be simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If the previous were 1 and the current were 1000, you would return 99900%  As previousPrice approaches 0, the percentage increase approaches infinite.

What you should do instead is to describe the change a different way. e.g. you say the price is now X, without reference to a percentage increase.

Comment: these returns are plugged into other formulas, so i will need to input a number,

Comment: In that case, you need to plug in infinite or the largest number it can represent.  The problem is you are applying a model which doesn't make sense in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter mentioned, percent return doesn't make any sense if the previous price was 0. Therefore, you should simply ignore any cases where the previous price was 0. Otherwise, the results you get from the other formulas won't have much meaning.

One way to do this is to return "N/A" in that case, and either values of "N/A" for calculation purposes or return "N/A" in those cases as well. This way you limit the impact of such cases, but it wouldn't be a bad idea to add a caveat of something like "where applicable". IE: "the average return was X, where applicable", since the average of any list of numbers containing infinity (unless perhaps it's an infinite list) is infinity.